# update valence shifter in sentimentr package in r

Tags: r

I am trying to remove certain rows from the lexicon::hash_valence_shifters in the sentimentr package. Specifically, i want to keep only rows:

c( 1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  6  , 7 , 13,  14 , 16 , 19,  24,  25 , 26,  27 , 28,  36,  38,  39,  41,  42,  43,  45,  46,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  59,  60,  65,  70,  71,  73,  74,  79,  84,  85,  87,  88,  89,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 114, 115, 119, 120, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 135, 136, 138)

I have tried the below approach:

```
vsm = lexicon::hash_valence_shifters[c, ]

vsm[ , y := as.numeric(y)]

vsm = sentimentr::as_key(vsm, comparison = NULL, sentiment = FALSE)

sentimentr::is_key(vsm)

vsn = sentimentr::update_valence_shifter_table(vsm, drop = c(dropvalue$x), x= lexicon::hash_valence_shifters, sentiment = FALSE, comparison = TRUE )
```

However, when I am calculating the sentiment using the updated valence shifter table "vsn", it is giving the sentiment as 0.

Can someone please let me know how to just keep specific rows of the valence shifter table ?

Thanks!